# Is there a way to get the connection string from a SQL DB then use that through the application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net-4.0, sql-server-2012

I am just doing some research at the moment into this and would like to know if it's possible.

I have an application where someone logs in with a username/ I would like to have a table with all the company id's stored and depending on which one they log in using it will use a connection string from the DB for that company.

I am fully aware of how to do it with the web.config but want to minimise the information kept here because potentially we are talking of around 1,000 connection strings.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more why you have 1,000 different connection strings?  Does each client have its own DB?

Comment: Why are there 1,000 different connection strings?  Do you really have 1,000 different databases?  All you've described is a table of company records, nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure create a table or modify an existing table.

```
CREATE TABLE Connection
(
     Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,ConnectionString VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Connection (ConnectionString)
VALUES ('Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;');
```

I would advise against storing passwords in the connection string when the contents of the table are unencrypted. Setup a domain account with Sql Server privileges to run your IIS app pool or Windows Service under.

```
const string Query = "SELECT ConnectionString FROM Connection WHERE Id = @Id";

public string GetConnectionString(int id)
{

    using(var connection = GetConnection())
    using(var command = new SqlCommand(Query, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
        connection.Open();

        using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if(reader.Read())
            {
                return Convert.ToString(reader["ConnectionString"]);
            }
        }
    }
}

var connectionString = GetConnectionString(1);
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    //logic
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible.

Store the connection strings in your (main?) DB, retrieve them and use them when instantiating new [`DdConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)s.

Most of the classes that inherit from `DbConnection` ([`SqlConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx), for example) have a constructor overload that takes a connection string.

Comment: In a chicken and egg scenario, you have to be able to connect to the db that contains the connections strings.

Comment: @DanBracuk - not really. You have a single connection string in the `.config` to a central DB that contains all the other ones.

Comment: True, but I thought that detail was worth mentioning.